# Swift 3 - Crashing after numberOfRowsInSection in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tableview

I migrated to Swift 3.0 from 2.3 today and I fixed all the compiler error messages, but I am having issues with one `TableView`. I put a breakpoint after all the datasource methods after I call `reloadData()` and it enters `numberOfSections` but crashes after it leaves `numberOfRowsInSection`. `cellForRowAt` is never hit. It crashes in the `AppDelegate`, so I am not sure what that is all about.

I did not previously have this issue when running Swift 2.3, unless the automatic conversion to 3.0 did something to this particular `TableView`. My other `TableView`s are functioning fine.

[image: Code]

[image: Crash]

Comment: add execptional break point to know where exactly its crashing. read more https://www.natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-trick/

Comment: there will be a crash reason printed in console check that

Comment: Paste code instead of image.

Comment: Make sure `podcasts` value is not `nil`, if it is an optional one.

Comment: If podcast.count is nil or 0 than the app will crash. @Alan

Comment: @KAR: 0 won't cause a crash. Crash happen if podcast is nil

Comment: Easy solution: Declare `podcasts` as non-optional empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //if self.podcasts.count is nil then 0 will be returned. 
       if let count = self.podcasts.count{ 
             return count
       }
    return 0
}
```

If you're loading something into podcasts asynchronously and reloading the tableview at same time then podcasts might be nil and which causes the crash.

Comment: I am initializing the podcasts as `var podcasts = [PodcastObj]()` so it is never nil.

Comment: On crash something will be posted in the console. What does PodcastObj have.

Comment: I figured it out... sorry for the red herring. It seems the crash happened due to a switch statement inside the Alamofire response block. It looked like it was the `UITableView` crashing due to it being async.

Comment: Ah, due to async the podcast obj was nil and tableview was crashing. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your array is empty or having nil value. Try to load rows by checking the count that contained in your array list.

Follow below code to avoid this error:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //Check array count here and return number of rows as same as array count otherwise return 0 rows 
   if self.podcasts.count > 0 { 
         return self.podcasts.count
   }
   else { 
         return 0
   }
```

Follow this steps always to avoid crashes like this.. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this as count will be automatically managed only object is getting `nil`
Some how
`return self.podcasts != nil ? self.podcasts!.count : 0`